# Using Cocos2d-x SEL_CallFunc

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I'm trying to make a custom sprite, which could receive touch and handle the function as callback.

Okay, first step, receive the touch, easy, we can search it online everywhere.
The one I couldn't do is, I want to make it receive SOMETHING in the class the sprite is created, a function that will be called when the sprite is touched.

I was searching on internet and I think (not really sure) that SEL_Callfunc can do what I want, but I couldn't understand how this one work, so can you guys give me an example please?

For example, my custom class is BSprite, so when I create new object in HelloWorld.cpp, it should be

```
    BSprite* sprite = BSprite::create("HelloWorld.png",HelloWorld::TouchCallback);
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sprite->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::onTouchSprite, this));

void HelloWorld::onTouchSprite() {
}
```

Note: onTouchSprite method should not have any parameters

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I know how to add listener to touch event, but I want to make a custom sprite that can be reuse easily in other projects, so I need a way to pass a function as parameter to the sprite when creating it :)